# Setting Inline Styles with JavaScript Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-edge

I've been working on a website which requires that inline styles be set to elements by the JavaScript. The styles do have to be inline because the values they need to be set to are determined in the JavaScript.
So far, this code has worked in most browsers (Gears.leftBot refers to the element):

```
Gears.leftBot.style = "transform: rotate(20deg);";
```

However, in Microsoft Edge, this code does nothing. I've even run this line of code in the console directly with no result (was able to confirm that it does recognize Gears.leftBot as an element). What can I do to fix this?

Complete JavaScript:

```
var Gears = {
    //Dependencies
    rightTop: document.getElementById('gear-rt'),
    rightMid: document.getElementById('gear-rm'),
    rightBot: document.getElementById('gear-rb'),
    leftTop: document.getElementById('gear-lt'),
    leftBot: document.getElementById('gear-lb'),

    init : function(){
        Gears.scrollAnima();
    },

    scrollAnima : function(){
        var pos = window.pageYOffset;
        var bigGearDeg = pos / 1.389;
        var midGearDeg = pos * 1.2;
        var litGearDeg = pos * 1.44;
        Gears.rightTop.style = "transform: rotate(" + bigGearDeg + "deg);";
        Gears.rightMid.style = "transform: rotate(-" + midGearDeg + "deg);";
        Gears.rightBot.style = "transform: rotate(" + litGearDeg + "deg);";
        Gears.leftTop.style = "transform: rotate(" + litGearDeg + "deg);";
        Gears.leftBot.style = "transform: rotate(-" + bigGearDeg + "deg);";
        setTimeout(function(){Gears.scrollAnima()}, 15);
    }
};

Gears.init();
```

Comment: Side-note, use requestAnimationFrame instead of setTimeout 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Gears.leftBot.style.transform = 'rotate(20deg)'
```

or:

```
Gears.leftBot.setAttribute('style', 'transform: rotate(20deg);')
```